# Export different ssh-keys from gpg subkeys

Tags: ssh, gnupg

I have a **GPG** master-key for certificating and a bunch of subkeys for encrypting, signing, auth. Is it possible to export different **ssh** public keys from each auth subkey I have?
E.g. I want to use the **pass** (passwordstore.org) and I've created a gpg key, 1 `E` subkey for encryption 3 `A` keys for auth on github for different pass clients. But when I export `--export-ssh-keys` with different `KeyID` (for each `A` subkey), I get the same public key every time.
Do I miss the concept of subkeys and it's not possible to have different auth subkeys belonging to one master key (i.e. I should made 1 gpg keypair for encrypting, and 3 keypairs for auth, all their own master key and own passphrase)?
My goal was to have one set of keys, with one passphrase, which contains everything down to my pass storage, i.e. 1 key for encrypting passwords (because it must be the same on each client) and auth keys for all clients to perform sync.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, after more research than this would deserve!

You can list your subkeys with fingerprints using `gpg -k --with-subkey-fingerprint`, and get the fingerprint of the key you want to export. Then it is as simple as adding an `!` at the end of the fingerprint:

`gpg --export "fingerprint"!`

where `"fingerprint"` is for your specific subkey.